# paste values within categories defined by multiple columns

Tags: r, aggregate, reshape2

I want to pivot the `result` column in `df` horizontally creating a data set with a separate row for each
`region`, `state`, `county` combination where the columns are ordered by `year` then `city`.

I also want to identify each row in the new data set by `region`, `state` and `county` and remove the white space between the four `results` columns.  The code below does all of that, but I suspect it is not very efficient.

Is there a way to do this with `reshape2` without creating a unique identifier for each group and numbering observations within each group?  Is there a way to use apply in place of the for-loop to remove white space from a matrix? (Matrix here being used in a different manner than a mathematical or programming construct.)  I realize those are two separate questions and maybe I should post each question separately.

Given that I can achieve the desired result and am only looking to improve the code I do not know whether I should even post this, but I am hoping to learn.  Thanks for any advice.

```
df <- read.table(text= "
region   state    county city  year result
1          1        1      1     1     1
1          1        1      2     1     2
1          1        1      1     2     3
1          1        1      2     2     4
1          1        2      3     1     4
1          1        2      4     1     3
1          1        2      3     2     2
1          1        2      4     2     1
1          2        1      1     1     0
1          2        1      2     1    NA
1          2        1      1     2     0
1          2        1      2     2     0
1          2        2      3     1     2
1          2        2      4     1     2
1          2        2      3     2     2
1          2        2      4     2     2
2          1        1      1     1     9
2          1        1      2     1     9
2          1        1      1     2     8
2          1        1      2     2     8
2          1        2      3     1     1
2          1        2      4     1     0
2          1        2      3     2     1
2          1        2      4     2     0
2          2        1      1     1     2
2          2        1      2     1     4
2          2        1      1     2     6
2          2        1      2     2     8
2          2        2      3     1     3
2          2        2      4     1     3
2          2        2      3     2     2
2          2        2      4     2     2
", header=TRUE, na.strings=NA)

desired.result <- read.table(text= "
region   state    county results
1          1        1     1234
1          1        2     4321
1          2        1     0.00
1          2        2     2222
2          1        1     9988
2          1        2     1010
2          2        1     2468
2          2        2     3322
", header=TRUE, colClasses=c('numeric','numeric','numeric','character'))

# redefine variables for package reshape2 creating a unique id for each
# region, state, county combination and then number observations in
# each of those combinations

library(reshape2)

id.var <- df$region*100000 + df$state*1000 + df$county
obsnum <- sequence(rle(id.var)$lengths)

df2 <- dcast(df, region + state + county ~ obsnum, value.var = "result")

# remove spaces between columns of results matrix
# with a for-loop.  How can I use apply to do this?

x <- df2[,4:(4+max(obsnum)-1)]

# use a dot to represent a missing observation

x[is.na(x)] = '.'

x.cat = numeric(nrow(x))

for(i in 1:nrow(x)) {
  x.cat[i] = paste(x[i,], collapse="")
}

df3 <- cbind(df2[,1:3],x.cat)
colnames(df3) <- c("region", "state", "county", "results")
df3

df3 == desired.result
```

EDIT:

Matthew Lundberg's answer below is excellent.  Afterwards I realized I also needed to create an output data set in which the four result columns above contain numeric, rational numbers and are separated by a space.  So, I have posted an apparent way to do that below that modifies Matthew's answer.  I do not know whether this is accepted protocol, but the new scenario seems so immediately related to the original post that I did not think I should post a new question.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think this does what you want:

```
df$result <- as.character(df$result)
df$result[is.na(df$result)] <- '.'


aggregate(result ~ county+state+region, data=df, paste0, collapse='')

  county state region result
1      1     1      1   1234
2      2     1      1   4321
3      1     2      1   0.00
4      2     2      1   2222
5      1     1      2   9988
6      2     1      2   1010
7      1     2      2   2468
8      2     2      2   3322
```

This relies on your data frame being sorted in the proper order (as yours is).

Comment: Thank you for the outstanding answer.  Later I realized I also needed an output data set in which the four result columns are numeric and are separated by a space.  I could not modify your answer to do that, but I came close, and posted the code here.

Answer (score 0):

Matthew Lundberg's answer is excellent. Afterwards I realized I also needed to create an output data set in which the four result columns above contain numeric, rational numbers and are separated by a space. So, here I provide an apparent way to do that using a modification of Matthew's answer. I do not know whether this is accepted protocol, but the new scenario seems so immediately related to the original post that I did not think I should post a new question.

The first two lines are modifications of Matthew's answer.

```
df$result[is.na(df$result)] <- 'NA'
df2 <- aggregate(result ~ county+state+region, data=df, paste)
```

Then I specify that `NA` represents missing observations and use `apply` to obtain the numeric output.

```
df2$result[df2$result=='NA'] = NA
new.df <- data.frame(df2[,1:3], apply(df2$result,2,as.numeric))
```

The output is below except note that I added 0.5 to each value in `df` shown in the original post.

```
  county state region  X1  X2  X3  X4
     1     1      1   1.5 2.5 3.5 4.5
     2     1      1   4.5 3.5 2.5 1.5
     1     2      1   0.5  NA 0.5 0.5
     2     2      1   2.5 2.5 2.5 2.5
     1     1      2   9.5 9.5 8.5 8.5
     2     1      2   1.5 0.5 1.5 0.5
     1     2      2   2.5 4.5 6.5 8.5
     2     2      2   3.5 3.5 2.5 2.5
```

Answer (score 0):

In my original post I asked how to remove spaces between columns in a data set using `apply`.  That did not prove necessary thanks to Matthew Lundberg's answer to my larger question.  Nevertheless, removing spaces between columns of a data set is something I frequently have to do.  For completeness, here I post a way to do that using `paste0` and `apply` that arose, in part, from Matthew's answer.

To remove all spaces from the data set `x`:

```
x <- read.table(text= "
A    B    C    D
1    1    1    1
1    1    2    2
1   NA    1    3
1    1    2    4
1    2    1    5
1    2   NA    6
1    2    1    7
1    2    2    8
", header=TRUE, na.strings=NA)

# use a dot to represent a missing observation

x[is.na(x)] = '.'

y <- as.data.frame(apply(x, 1, function(i) paste0(i, collapse='')))
colnames(y) <- 'result'
y
```

Gives:

```
  result
1   1111
2   1122
3   1.13
4   1124
5   1215
6   12.6
7   1217
8   1228
```

The following code removes the spaces between just the second and third columns:

```
z <- as.data.frame(apply(x[,2:3], 1, function(i) paste0(i, collapse='')))

y <- data.frame(x[,1], z, x[,4])
colnames(y) <- c('A','BC','D')
y
```

Giving:

```
  A BC D
1 1 11 1
2 1 12 2
3 1 .1 3
4 1 12 4
5 1 21 5
6 1 2. 6
7 1 21 7
8 1 22 8
```

Comment: No need to create the anonymous functions for `apply`.  Use the `...` argument to pass to `paste0` instead.  `apply(x, 1, paste0, collapse='')`,